# Como ajustar o tamanho de um geom_plot já incorporado a outro gráfico do ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Nesta situação abaixo, como eu poderei ajustar o tamanho do `geom_plot()` adicionado ao `geom_jitter()` uma vez que a função `tibble(x = 12, y = 4.5, plot = list(dens_iris))` só permitiu identificar a interseção de x e y do canto superior direito?

```
data("iris")

require(ggplot2)
require(ggridges)

dens_iris <- ggplot(iris,aes(y = Species, x = Sepal.Length, fill=factor(..quantile..))) +
  stat_density_ridges(geom = "density_ridges_gradient",
                      calc_ecdf = TRUE,
                      quantiles = c(0.025, 0.975)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_text(size = 8),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.5,"cm"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 8))


jitter_iris <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width,
                                     shape = Species, fill = Species)) +
  geom_jitter(size = 3.5,alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_smooth(size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(4,12)) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.9,0.1))

require(dplyr)
data.tb <- tibble(x = 12, y = 4.5, plot = list(dens_iris))

require(ggpmisc)
pl <- jitter_iris + geom_plot(data = data.tb, aes(x, y, label = plot))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use os argumentos `vp.width` e `vp.height` dentro do `aes` do `geom_plot`. Ambos os argumentos `vp.width` e `vp.height` variam de 0 a 1, onde 0 é o menor valor possível para o gráfico inserido e 1 é um gráfico inserido que ocupa a área inteira do gráfico original.

**Gráfico padrão, ocupando 1/3 das dimensões dos eixos**

```
jitter_iris + 
  geom_plot(data = data.tb, aes(x, y, label = plot))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Gráfico modificado, ocupando 1/2 das dimensões dos eixos**

```
jitter_iris + 
  geom_plot(data = data.tb, aes(x, y, label = plot, 
                                vp.width = 0.5, 
                                vp.height = 0.5))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Gráfico modificado, ocupando 1/5 das dimensões dos eixos**

```
jitter_iris + 
  geom_plot(data = data.tb, aes(x, y, label = plot, 
                                vp.width = 0.2, 
                                vp.height = 0.2))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]